# JPA/Hibernate one-to-one cascade removal in a modular application

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two entity classes from two different modules in a multi-module application. One entity has a unidirectional one-to-one relationship on another.

The primary entity "Song" is from a module song-core and it's defined something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Song {
   @Id(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;
   private String name;
}
```

And the next entity called "SongLyrics" is from the module "song-lyrics", which is defined something like:

```
@Entity
public class SongLyrics {
  @Id(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  @OneToOne
  private Song song;
  @Column(nullable = false, length=1024)
  private String lyrics;
}
```

Since SongLyrics entity is from the optional "song-lyrics" module, which might or might not be available in the final application, the relationship it has with "Song" entity is unidirectional.

Now I want the "SongLyrics" entity to be removed, whenever a "Song" entity is deleted. But what's happening now is the "SongLyrics" entities are left as "orphans" and only the "Song" entities are getting deleted.

Please give your insights on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SongLyrics` can't have it's one identity in a one-to-one relation. One-to-one means that they share the same primary key. When using a normal foreign key in the database to point from the `SongLyrics` to the `Song`, it is a many-to-one relation.

The problem is that there is no relation from the `Song` to the `SongLyrics`, so cascading from hibernate doesn't work.

These are the options coming to my mind:

- create a many-to-any relation from the `Song` to the `SongLyrics` to decouple the types and still be able to cascade (and navigate).
- Use a kind of events in your application to inform the modules when something gets deleted to allow them to clean up (or even to veto).
- Use database triggers to remove the `SongLyrics`.

Comment: Small correction: `@OneToOne` creates a foregin key based one-to-one relationships, the same as `<many-to-one unique = "true" ...>`.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan and @axtavt for your suggestions.

I'll update SongLyrics so that the FK to Song is also the primary key.

But as @Stefan highlighted, there will be still no relation from Song to SongLyrics, mainly because they span across modules. And that's why hibernate (or any JPA provider) couldn't propagate the "cascading" effect.

Thanks Stefan for the second and third suggestions. I was pondering about using Spring AOP to handle this but if there are any portable ways to create database triggers that would be fine as well.